# Mvc Html.Partial() not working when called with ViewDataDictionary parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Controller called `C` and it has an action named `A`. I also have a shared view called `_Navigation` (`Views/Shared/_Navigation.cshtml`). In the middle of the file (`Views/C/A.cshtml`) I have a code like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_Navigation")
```

All works well, the navigation is loaded. However, if I try to call

```
@Html.Partial("_Navigation", new ViewDataDictionary() { { "foo", "bar"}})
```

suddenly the navigation part is not loaded in the page. I also tried

```
@Html.Partial("~Views/Shared/_Navigation", new ViewDataDictionary() { { "foo", "bar"}})
@Html.Partial("../Shared/_Navigation", new ViewDataDictionary() { { "foo", "bar"}})

@Html.Partial("~Views/Shared/_Navigation", null, new ViewDataDictionary() { { "foo", "bar"}})
@Html.Partial("../Shared/_Navigation", null, new ViewDataDictionary() { { "foo", "bar"}})
```

Neither of these worked. I had put the breakpoint in `_Navigation` and it was even hit! It also continued through all the view without crashing. There was no error shown in either console in Chrome, output or anywhere in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was overwriting the whole ViewDataDictionary and should have called like this:

```
@{ ViewData.Add("foo", "bar"); }

@Html.Partial("_Navigation", ViewData)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 

don't know with when you call it like this 

@{ 
    ViewData.Add("foo", "bar"); 
    Html.Partial("_Navigation", ViewData)
}

it just does not work.